# Changing color rendering of multiple raster layers at once

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I have many raster layers in my QGIS project and they're all currently rendered as:
Multiband color
Red band: Band 1
Green band: Band 2
Blue band: Band 3

I'd like to know if there's any way I can change the rendering of all raster layers to:
Red band: Band 3
Green band: Band 2
Blue band: Band 1
without having to do it by hand, layer by layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pyqgis. This will change symbology of all raster layers in layer tree to red band=band 3, green=band 2, blue=band 1:

```
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if isinstance(lyr, qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer): #Check to make sure it is a raster layer
        r = lyr.renderer().clone()
        r.setRedBand(3)
        r.setGreenBand(2)
        r.setBlueBand(1)
        lyr.setRenderer(r)
        lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I've ran into some trouble. The bands change accordingly, but the changes don't apply unless I go into each layer's symbology and hit the "Apply" button. I tried using triggerRepaint() and other similar methods like `qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` but they don't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: Try now, I've changed the code!

Comment: The same thing still happens. I think it has something to do with applying the "stretch to min-max" contrast settings. I tried working around it with something like this:

`layer = iface.activeLayer()
contrastFilter = QgsBrightnessContrastFilter()
contrastFilter.setContrast(50)
layer.pipe().set(contrastFilter)
layer.triggerRepaint()`

but it basically does nothing

Answer (score 2):

Set it up for one layer.

Right click that layer, Styles -> Copy Style.

Select all the other layers you want to apply the same style to, right-click, Styles -> Paste Style.